# SCIP _ How to get started

Tags: scip

I hope this is not a frequently asked question but i could not find anything with the search function that helped me.

I have to solve a linear program for my bachelorthesis and my professor said SCIP will be good to use. I will use the Win 7 binary file.

I have coded in C and JAVA before, but never worked with LP's before and have no clue on how to use SCIP. I tried to understand it with the documentation site over here: http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/index.php
But this doesnt help me that much.

Can you give some tips on how do i get started?

I hope you can help me.
Sincerely,
Moritz

Comment: While your enthusiasm is appreciated, please come back, and edit your question when you have done some research and attempted it yourself. The question alone is far too board and open-ended for SO.

Comment: Although you can in theory use the Windows binary, I would strongly suggest to use SCIP on Linux. The main reason is the availability of the readiine library that makes the use of SCIP a lot easier than on Windows. Unfortunately, we cannot include them into the downloadable binary, so you would have to compile the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you need to model your problem as an LP or MIP first. Have a look at the [documentation](http://zimpl.zib.de/download/zimpl.pdf) of [ZIMPL](http://zimpl.zib.de). Next, you could browse the various presentations about SCIP from the last [SCIP workshop](http://scip.zib.de/workshop/).